# Reading Roman numerals in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've been playing with Haskell data types for the past few days, using a custom type to work with Roman numerals:

```
data RomanNumeral = I | IV | V | IX | X | XL | L | XC | C | CD | D | CM | M deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)

stringToRomanNumeral :: String -> Maybe [RomanNumeral]
stringToRomanNumeral romString
    | unRoman = Nothing
    | otherwise = Just $ map read $ map (\x -> [x]) romStringUpper
    where 
        romStringUpper = map C.toUpper romString
        unRoman = any (`notElem` "MDCLXVI") romStringUpper
```

This works fine, but catches only 1-char numerals (so I have to calculate the value of IV, IX etc. later on).

Is there a way to `read` (or `reads`) the input string such that the returned value of Maybe [RomanNumeral] contains 2-char numerals, too? I tried dabbling with pattern matching, but I cannot seem to get the type right.

Comment: If instead you have only the actual numerals in the datatype, says I, V, X, C, D, M - you could represent the full number as a list of these numerals. This would simplify things quite a bit.

Comment: My original approach was restricted to I, V, X, C, D, M, and the stringToRomanNumeral function returns these items. But having IV, IX etc. as separate type constructors greatly simplifies the conversion of decimal numbers (not shown here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `reads` doesn't work well because it expects tokens, it won't split up e.g. `"XIV"` into `"X"` and `"IV"` to obtain two parseable parts, it regards the entire char sequence as one token since they belong to the same character class. You can write your own parser for roman numerals (and you should try, writing parsers is fun) taking care of special sequences.

A simplistic approach is

```
module Roman where

import Data.Char as C

data RomanNumeral = I | IV | V | IX | X | XL | L | XC | C | CD | D | CM | M
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)

stringToRomanNumeral :: String -> Maybe [RomanNumeral]
stringToRomanNumeral = fmap collate . sequence . map (toRom . C.toUpper)
  where
    romDict = zip "IVXLCDM" [I,V,X,L,C,D,M]
    toRom = flip lookup romDict

collate :: [RomanNumeral] -> [RomanNumeral]
collate (x:ys@(y:zs)) = case lookup (x,y) collationDict of
                          Just v -> v : collate zs
                          Nothing -> x : collate ys
collate xs = xs

collationDict :: [((RomanNumeral,RomanNumeral),RomanNumeral)]
collationDict =
    [ ((I,V),IV)
    , ((I,X),IX)
    , ((X,L),XL)
    , ((X,C),XC)
    , ((C,D),CD)
    , ((C,M),CM)
    ]
```

it's not very flexible either, any bad character will lead to a `Nothing` result, but that's easily modifiable (one could use `catMaybes` instead of `sequence` to simply ignore invalid characters for example). And it does not check the general (modern) 'decreasing value' rule (which makes interpreting 'IX' as 9 instead of 11 possible). Checking validity can however be done after parsing.

Comment: IC and XD are today by convention not allowed, and are written XCIX and CDXC.

Comment: Learn something new every other day. Thanks.

Comment: @RobAgar As far as I remember the `IV = 4` rule is a relatively recent invention, the Romans just added all numerals to arrive at the total.

Comment: I think the reason why clocks write `IIII` instead of `IV` is because you get a nice 20:4:4 ratio between the `I`, `V` and `X`.

Comment: Excellent – thanks a lot! My attempt to parse and collate in one step/function was obviously a bad idea. I do check validity be feeding the integer result to the reverse function (convertDecimal).

Comment: I generally use something like the shunting yard algorithm to parse roman numerals: produces a number given any sequence of [IVXLCDM], and produces the correct number if the sequence is a valid Roman numeral.

Answer (score 0):

I think the current way you are using the RomanNumeral datatype is inherently a bad idea.

You should also override show/read instead of relying on the default set.

Perhaps

```
-- underlying datatype as int
data RomanNumeral = RomanNumeral Int

instance Show RomanNumeral where
    show (RomanNumeral x) = -- your code for converting a roman numeral to a string

instance Read RomanNumeral where
    readsPred d r = -- your code for reading a string into an integer and then return a RomanNumeral
```

Comment: I get the idea, but I would still need to map the numeral symbols to their respective decimal values. Having a RomanNumeral item which contains an Int value does not solve this problem (or rather: I cannot see how it does).